# Configurable SQL GROUP BY variable

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, group-by, aggregate-functions

I am currently developing some SQL aggregation queries to calculate data from one source table. The goal is, to have different aggregation granularities in one executable query / function / etc. I am currently developing on PostgreSQL but the code should be ANSI SQL compliant as much as possible to be compatible to most DB variants.

Example:

```
SELECT
   COUNT(a) as amount,
   SUM(b) as sum,
   c as static_grouping,
   @vargr as variable_grouping,
   @vardesc as variable_grouping_description
FROM whatever
GROUP BY c, @vargr, @vardesc
```

@vargr can be date driven like daily, weekly, monthly, ...
@vardesc is the identifier to see aggregation type as text

Having multiple queries with UNION is not an option, since there are multiple grouping statements changing (resulting in 60+ single queries per result set). Is there a way to do this with a function, while loop, etc.?

Thanks for a hint in the right direction, have a good day and stay safe!

Best regards
Christian

Comment: To specify even more:

Comment: That's a parameter, not a variable. Parameters contain *values*, not references to fields or tables. What you wrote groups by `c`1 and two constants, so it's essentially just a `GROUP BY c`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*If* you want to group by varying date granularity, then one option uses `date_trunc()`. You would typically use one of the supported precision (such as `day`, `week`, `month` and so on) as parameter. Assuming that your date or timestamp column is `tscol`, you would do:

```
SELECT
   COUNT(a) as amount,
   SUM(b) as sum,
   c as static_grouping,
   DATE_TRUNC($1, tscol) as variable_grouping,
   $2 as variable_grouping_description
FROM whatever
GROUP BY c, DATE_TRUNC($1, tscol)
```

Comment: Hi GMB, thanks for the answer, this solves the date issue already but I also have more complicated scenarios, e.g. GROUP BY (partial ZIP Code, ZIP Code, City, Province, ...) where ZIP Code, City and Province are individual columns in a table, so I have to exchange the Group By and selected column based on the current level of aggregation. Is there a similar solution to this? Thanks

Comment: @jspawn . . . I think this answers the question you asked.  If you have a different question, then ask a *new* question.